# Vim publishing script

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a vim script that, when I save, duplicates my changes to a second directory. In this case the second directory is on a VM that I can ssh to.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it manually add this to your vimrc:

```
command! DuplicateFileRemotely !scp % user@remotehost:~/mylocation/
```

Then call it in command mode:

```
:DuplicateFileRemotely
```

If you want to do it every time a file is saved add this too your vimrc as well:

```
autocmd! BufWritePost * :DuplicateFileRemotely
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed. Though everyone's answers were pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the filesystem locally then you can use cp. Add this to your your .vimrc and change the path.

```
autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.* silent !cp <afile> /your/remote/path &
```

If you can only access ssh then use scp or rsync.

```
autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.* silent !scp -Cr <afile> ssh://hostname:remote/path &
```

If you just want this to happen for certain file extensions change the `*.*` to say `*.py` to only copy Python files for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a key mapping to write to 2 locations, for example:

```
map <C-s> :w<ENTER>:w /path/to/alt/dir/%<ENTER>
```

This will map Ctrl-s to to you double save, saving the file to it's current location and also to your alternate directory with the same file name.

Answer (score 0):

Vim can automatically save copies to a "backup directory" (assuming you can map the location on your local filesystem). See `:h backupdir` for more information on this option, or view help on the web here:  http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backupdir%27